# Is there an equivalent of DETAIL DISK in Parted or other Linux DISKPART type consoles?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, gparted, parted

Im trying to scrape information of drive type. EG USB, RAID Etc..

In windows I can use DISKPART and run the command DETAIL DISK :

Example:

---

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

WDC WD1600AAJS-75M0A0
Disk ID: 46C9XXXX
Type   : RAID
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 4
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1F02)#RAID(P00T04L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info

---

Volume 2     D                NTFS   Partition     97 GB  Healthy    System

---

So what is the equivalent command (if it exists) in Parted or other command line utility for Linux?

The key information I am after is the "Type : RAID" output.

I'm looking to integrate a scrape in to an existing program.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look as **lsblk**. Per its **man** page: *"lsblk  lists  information  about  all available or the specified block devices."*, e.g:

`lsblk` (to retrieve info on all block devices):

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 273.4G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 272.9G  0 part 
  ├─neuron--vg-root   252:0    0 144.9G  0 lvm  /
  └─neuron--vg-swap_1 252:1    0   128G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                     8:16   0   1.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   1.7T  0 part /home
```

`lsblk /dev/sd* --nodeps --output TYPE`(to retrieve *Type* for all block devices):

```
TYPE
disk
part
part
part
disk
part
```

`lsblk /dev/sd* --nodeps --output NAME,MODEL,VENDOR,SIZE,TYPE,STATE`(to retrieve specified parameters on all block devices):

```
NAME MODEL            VENDOR     SIZE TYPE STATE
sda  LOGICAL VOLUME   HP       273.4G disk running
sda1                             487M part 
sda2                               1K part 
sda5                           272.9G part 
sdb  LOGICAL VOLUME   HP         1.7T disk running
sdb1                             1.7T part
```

`lsblk /dev/sda --nodeps --output TYPE` (to get *Type* of *sda*, which is generally the equivalent of *Window's Disk 1*):

```
TYPE
disk
```

This is one approach, and you may need to add the package to your particular distribution with, e.g.: `sudo apt-get install lsblk` (Debian, Ubuntu).